# How come my route isn't matching with React Router 4?

Tags: react-router-v4

I have a routes file that works as expected:

```
<Route path="/app" render={({match}) => (
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path={`${match.url}/`} component={Home} />
        <Route path={`${match.url}/error`} component={Error} />
    </Switch>
</Route>
```

But when I try to hard code the routes, it does not work.  For example:

```
<Route path="/app" render={({match}) => (
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path={`app/`} component={Home} />
        <Route path={`app/error`} component={Error} />
    </Switch>
</Route>
```

Of course hard coding is not what I really want, but in case I wanted to do something like this

```
<Route path="/app">
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="app/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="app/error" component={Error} />
    </Switch>
</Route>
```

And create the app using the `Children` of the `Route` and not the `render` prop.  What am I doing wrong, or how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

React router V4 doesn't use nested routes.

`<Route path="/app">` will match anything that begins with `/app`, which I don't think is what you want.

This should be enough to do what you want:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path={`/app/error`} component={Error} />
  <Route path={`/app`} component={Home} />
</Switch>
```